# add note to CLOCK entry after clocking out

Tags: org-mode

After clocking out, I would like Emacs to prompt me for a note, as when I switch the state of an entry to a state that requires an annotation.

Use case: During the day I work in several things related to one main task, which I set an entry for it in my org-mode document and clock on, and I cannot specify what is going to be work on beforehand, otherwise I would create a sub-entry and log the time there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will answer myself stating that the variable `org-log-note-clock-out` exists for this very purpose. Set it to `t` to add a note after clocking out.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: The `org-log-note-clock-out` variable controls whether the user is prompted to enter a note after clocking out.  When set to `t`, a popup buffer will be created whenever `org-clock-out` (`C-c C-x C-o`) is called.  You enter a note, then press `C-c C-c` to close the popup buffer.  The note is added immediately after the `CLOCK:` line.   The `org-log-note-clock-out` variable can be set globally using Emacs Lisp with `(setq org-log-note-clock-out t)` or per-buffer with `#+STARTUP: lognoteclock-out`.  NB: Check the documentation for definitive information (except Drew who already knows this!) :)

Comment: This is very helpful, especially when employing the method described here: https://jeffhuang.com/productivity_text_file/